# Need translation for a Thor’s hammer pendant

Tags: norse

I have a Thor’s hammer pendant that I bought years ago. I’m not sure what is written on it. A translation would be great! [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: I would have commented this, but I don't have high enough reputation.

This page may have the answer you are looking for. The runes there look just like yours but simplified [Freya's Rune Converter](http://attfreya.com/?r=ets)

If that page didn't help, here are some resources that you may be able to use:

[Viking Runes Guide](https://sonsofvikings.com/blogs/history/viking-runes-guide-runic-alphabet-meanings-nordic-celtic-letters)

[The Meanings of Runes](https://norse-mythology.org/runes/the-meanings-of-the-runes/)

[Viking Rune Meanings](https://viking.style/viking-rune-meanings/)

Also, here are my best guesses at what the runes are supposed to be:

Mannaz [image: Mannaz]: meaning man, human, or self

Peorth [image: Peorth]: meaning elder tree, feminine energy, sexuality.

This last one (in my opinion) could be either kaunaz [image: Kaunaz] or [image: sowulo]